# branch.io deeplinking not working

Tags: react-native, branch.io, ios-universal-links

So I've setup branch.io and universal links on my app and website but the deep link doesn't seem to be working

Using the dynamic link

https://foo.link?%24deeplink_path=event%2F99

I get redirected to

https://foo.com/?$deeplink_path=event%2F99

I was expecting it to go here instead

https://foo.com/event/99

Additionally - when I trigger the link in my app on device or simulator it doesn't deep link in or trigger the branch event functions in react native - but does open the app.

I've added the methods to AppDelegate and went through all the steps to deep link - did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alex from Branch here:

You're really close — this is just a minor misconception in how the various Branch configuration parameters work.

First of all, know that a Branch link can contain various 'control parameters' that define system behavior, *and* an unlimited number of custom `key:value` pairs.

On Android and iOS < 9 (both of which use URI schemes for deep linking), the `$deeplink_path` param is a control param: Branch automatically passes any value in this parameter into the standard URI path methods when the app opens. On iOS > 9 (which uses Universal Links), `$deeplink_path` is treated as just a 'normal' `key:value` pair, [but you can build some custom code to make it behave the same way as Android and iOS < 9](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/advanced/ios/#how-to-handle-uri-paths-with-universal-links).

Website redirects work a little bit differently. What you actually want here is the `$fallback_url` control parameter (or one of its platform-specific varients). This defines where non-app users will be redirected. In this case, `https://foo.link?%24fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Ffoo.com%2Fevent%2F99` should do what you want.

You can find documentation on all these configuration parameters [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/configuring-links/guide/)